# @LinkedIn Share article End Point is returning error 500

Tags: linkedin-api, share

I am trying to post article links to my linkedIn profile and when I tried the End point retuned error 500. I tries to post using the share media endpoint and when I tried it returned error 500. But when I try with just text share it is working fine. The link I was using is the
{
"author": "urn:li:person:8675309",
"lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
"specificContent": {
"com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
"shareCommentary": {
"text": "Learning more about LinkedIn by reading the LinkedIn Blog!"
},
"shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
"media": [
{
"status": "READY",
"description": {
"text": "Official LinkedIn Blog - Your source for insights and information about LinkedIn."
},
"originalUrl": "https://blog.linkedin.com/",
"title": {
"text": "Official LinkedIn Blog"
}
}
]
}
},
"visibility": {
"com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
}
}